# Class Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronRemoveCommand\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: php, magento2

While running the command php bin/magento setup:upgrade this error is showing again and again.

I am using Xampp and MAGENTO 2.3.3

Comment: In ClassReader.php line 19:

  Class Magento\Sales\Console\Command\EncryptionPaymentDataUpdateCommand\Interceptor does not exist

Comment: Sometimes its showing this error:-   Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try to run first

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

then try to upgrade and see if it works.

Hope it helps :D